# Is there a good way to link registered users' emails with data in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

If I build a website for my new awesome mobile app (or web service or whatever) I might want to do a slow launch, sending email invites to the first x people to register on the site.

Is there a good way to link each registered email to the corresponding data in google analytics (or any similar service), and query them based on location, language, etc.?

Maybe the spanish version isn't quite done yet, so I don't want to invite people who used a spanish browser to sign up. Or maybe my app is location-dependent (like time tables for buses) and just doesn't work at all outside of my home town.

I really want to have a simple email-only "registration".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely possible, although it may breach some of GA's [terms of use](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en) if done wrong.

You should **not** store email addresses in any way as part of your GA data because it would be considered *personally identifiable data*. However, there is nothing saying that you couldn't store a kind of GUID for each user, and then compare that with email addresses *offline* - although the user should be made aware that any actions they take while using your service/application/whatever are being tracked with the capability of being personally identified.

As far as getting the actual data that you are discussing, language and location are stored by GA by default, so no headache there!

The best way to store the user's GUID would probably be in a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets). How you do this is going to depend on how you build your product. I had to write a tracking library using the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) for an AS3 project awhile back because there isn't an AS3 library that is supported anymore. If you are using JavaScript, it will be much easier, as Google offers native JS libraries to handle web analytics.

Finally, try taking a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/). Its pretty easy to understand

Comment: "or data that permanently identifies a particular device (such as a mobile phone’s unique device identifier if such an identifier cannot be reset), even in hashed form." doesn't an email linked to a unique value count? That's personal information, but it isn't unique to any device and i suppose making it possible to remove oneself from the list would make it ok?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question - I'm honestly not sure how the TOS applies to data you have access to (but are not storing with GA). For example, you might store a unique clientId for each user using your application. That clientId may not link to any info stored by Google, but in theory could be linked to personal data that you store in your own external database. From my understanding, that would be fine as long as its covered in your own TOS with the users you're tracking.

Comment: My sole goal is to be able to get emails of all users who match a specific query, say all males 18-25 in Europe.